# Проблема с FK MS SQL

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[typesysid] (
    [systemid] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [textid]   NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_typesysid] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([systemid] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_typesysid_ToTable] FOREIGN KEY ([systemid]) REFERENCES [dbo].[catalog]([type]),
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[catalog] (
    [Id]      INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [name]    NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [autor]   NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [editor]  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [year]    NVARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    [about]   TEXT          NOT NULL,
    [type]    NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [picture] IMAGE         NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Результат:

> Update cannot proceed due to validation errors.   Please correct the
>   following errors and try again.
>
> SQL71516 :: The referenced table '[dbo].[catalog]' contains no primary
>   or candidate keys that match the referencing column list in the
>   foreign key. If the referenced column is a computed column, it should
>   be persisted.

FK уже был, корректно работал. Я немного увлекся и удалил что-то не то, в результате установить его обратно не могу с такой вот проблемой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FK должен ссылаться на уникальный ключ или индекс в другой таблице. А вы пытаетесь сослаться на неключевое поле `type nvarchar(50)`. Попробуйте создать уникальный индекс:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UX01_catalog ON dbo.catalog(type)
```

Comment: Не работает. SQL71515 ::  и SQL71558 :: .
Еще нюанс в том, что мне нужно связать systemid(nvarchar(50)) с type(nvarchar(50)). Именно по этим полям необходима связь.

Comment: @DisguisePerceptron в какую сторону должна быть связь? какая таблица главная, а какая-второстепенная?

Comment: @DisguisePerceptron ок, вроде понял что вы пытаетесь сделать (хотя не уверен, в какую сторону вам нужен FK). Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, что вы не в той таблице внешний ключ создаете. Наоборот, скорее всего, должно быть.

Comment: Попробовал так сделать.
Перестал работать код "SELECT c.*, t.* FROM catalog c JOIN typesysid t ON c.type=t.systemid", который до проблем с FК работал как нужно. Query Builder структуру показывает как нужно, но вот ничего не выводит.

Comment: @DisguisePerceptron этот запрос должен работать даже без FK, только чуть медленее. если "перестал работать" - значит проблема в данных.